# Issue with Docusign authentication registration flow

Tags: docusignapi

Our application offers Docusign integration.
Therefore, we allow our users to *Login to Docusign*.

Everything is fine when the user is already a Docusign user and logs in:

1. User taps on *Login to Docusign*
2. A browser is opened and redirected to Docusign login dialog where he enters his email address
3. He enters the email address
4. He enters his password
5. He is redirected to `callback_url`

However, when the user needs to register to Docusign, the process becomes like this:

1. User taps on *Login to Docusign*
2. A browser is opened and redirected to Docusign login dialog where he enters his email address
3. Since he doesnt have an email registered with docusign, he taps on "Register" link
4. An activation email is sent to his email address.
5. user clicks on the activation link in the email
6. User is redirected to his Docusign dashboard

The problem with this registration flow is that on step 6, the user is not being redirected to `callback_url`.
Therefore, the loop with our application is now broken and user is confused.

Shouldn't Docusign redirect users back to `callback_url` when activation is completed?

Comment: You're using the OAuth Authentication Code Grant flow?

Comment: @LarryK yes we are using the OAuth Authentication Code Grant flow

Comment: @LarryK any thoughts?

Comment: I have again asked internally. In the meantime, have you considered asking if the user has an account on DocuSign? Eg, give two options: Authenticate with DocuSign and "I need a DocuSign account"

Answer (score 0):

If your application's User Experience (UX) explicitly enables the user to either create an account on DocuSign or to sign in, then you can remove the "Create an account" option from the OAuth window:

In your initial GET to the DocuSign authentication server, include query parameter of

```
ui_flavors=no_sign_up
```

This should prevent the "Sign Up" links / options from being shown.

This is not the optimal answer for the question, but it is available now.